# Animating Bezier curve as though drawing proceeds on iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uibezierpath

I want to draw a bezier path of the outline of Taj Mahal's tomb.

Q1. How could I draw it in XCode? I could easily do that in PS but am finding it difficult to do in XCode programmatically especially getting the coordinates of the control points.

Q2. Moreover, how can the coordinates of the points be fixed when the screen sizes vary?

Q3. How could I animate it as though an invisible pencil is drawing that on screen?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### How do I draw a bezier path in `UIKit`?

Create a `UIBezierPath` object and then use the [various methods on it to construct your path](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009276-CH1-SW17).

I suspect the methods you're going to be most interested in are:

- [`moveToPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/moveToPoint:) (Fairly self-explanitary, moves the current point to a given point)
- [`addLineToPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addLineToPoint:) (Adds a straight line, starting at the current point and ending at a given point)
- [`addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:) (Adds a bezier curve, starting the current point, with a set end point and control points)
- [`addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addQuadCurveToPoint:controlPoint:) Adds a quadratic curve, starting at the current point, with a set end point and control point.

**For example, something like this will create a simple bezier path with a quadratic curve:**

```
UIBezierPath* yourPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; // create the bezier path
[yourPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100)]; // move to your starting point
[yourPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(300, 500) controlPoint:CGPointMake(500, 350)]; // add a new quad curve to the point
```

However, if you're used to using something like Photoshop to create your paths, you [may be interested in PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/), that can let you create bezier paths using a 'what you see is what you get' approach.

**You can add this `UIBezierPath` to the `path` property of a `CAShapeLayer` in order to display it on screen.**

```
CAShapeLayer* yourShapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer]; // create your shape layer
yourShapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 500); // assign it's frame
yourShapeLayer.path = yourPath.CGPath; // add your path to the shape layer
yourShapeLayer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; // prevent the shape layer from filling

[self.view.layer addSublayer:yourShapeLayer]; // add the shape layer to the view
```

**You can then easily set the `strokeColor` and `lineWidth` properties on the shape layer in order to customise how your path gets stroked.**

```
yourShapeLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor; // red stroke color
yourShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0; // 5 point stroke width
```

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

---

### How could I animate it as though an invisible pencil is drawing that on screen?

You can easily create a `CABasicAnimation` that can animate the `strokeStart` or `strokeEnd` property of the `CAShapeLayer` in order to achieve your desired animation.

This can result in the animation effect of the line 'getting drawn' onto the screen.

**For example, this code will result in the `strokeEnd` property animating from `0.0` to `1.0`, creating your desired effect:**

```
yourShapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.0; // reset stroke start before animating

CABasicAnimation* strokeAnim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"]; // create animation that changes the strokeEnd property
strokeAnim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]; // give it a nice timing function
strokeAnim.duration = 2.0; // duration of the animation
strokeAnim.fromValue = @(0.0); // provide the start value for the animation, wrapped in an NSNumber literal.
strokeAnim.toValue = @(1.0); // provide the end value for the animation, wrapped in an NSNumber literal.

[yourShapeLayer addAnimation:strokeAnim forKey:@"strokeAnim"]; // add animation to layer
```

[image]

---

### How can I scale this path to work with different sized screens?

The way I usually like to solve this problem is to **define the path's points in a given fixed frame** (let's say 500 x 500 points), and then **generate a scale factor based on the size of the screen** (in your case, you want to scale to the width of the screen).

So all we have to do is generate our scale factor.

```
CGFloat sf = self.view.frame.size.width/500.0; // The factor to scale the path by
```

Then, we just have to multiple all our points in the `UIBezierPath` by this scale factor. For example, taking our previous path:

```
UIBezierPath* yourPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; // create the bezier path
[yourPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(100.0*sf, 100.0*sf)]; // move to your starting point
[yourPath addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(300.0*sf, 500.0*sf) controlPoint:CGPointMake(500.0*sf, 350.0*sf)];
```

**Now, all we have to do is program in our bezier path points *as if* we were always drawing it in a 500 x 500 frame (my points already fit nicely within that).**

You'll also want to change the size of your `CAShapeLayer` so that it's squared and occupies the entire width of the screen.

```
yourShapeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.width);
```

Finally, you want to position the `CAShapeLayer` to the center of the screen. You can do this easily by setting the `position` property of the layer to the `center` of the view.

```
yourShapeLayer.position = self.view.center;
```

**Now your path should always scale to occupy the screen's width.**

[image]

(I added a gray background to the layer just to illustrate the scaling)

---

**Full project (for your convenience): https://github.com/hamishknight/Drawing-Scaling-Animating-UIBezierPaths**

Comment: I've added an extra question, how can the coordinates of the points be fixed when the screen sizes vary?

Comment: what do you mean by fixed? do you mean they scale up when the screen scales up? or do you mean they literally stay fixed?

Comment: Say, If I want the animation to be in a square frame which is always centered at the screen no matter the size of the device..then how do I do that using coordinates?

Comment: @Viki you'd just want to keep the size of the `CAShapeLayer` constant, and just adjust it's `position` to the center of the screen. You won't have to change the path itself. Although are you saying you also want the path to scale within that square frame?

Comment: Yea, I want the animation to scale according to the size of the device with it's relative position fixed like auto-layout. Like in an imageview, the image is shrinked or expanded according to the size of device..but the relative position of view itself is constant

Comment: Sure..I'll have my dinner as well meanwhile :)

Comment: @Viki I have updated my answer showing how you could do this.

Comment: @Hamish this is a brilliant response. Deserves more than an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

I blogged about this in 2010: [Animating the Drawing of a CGPath With CAShapeLayer](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/).

The gist of it is this:

- Create a `UIBezierPath` or `CGPath` with the shape you want to draw. Use the methods `moveToPoint:`, `addLineToPoint:`, 
  `addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:` etc. to create the shape.
- Create a `CGShapeLayer` and assign the path to the layer's `path` property.
- Add the layer to your view/layer hierarchy (e.g. in a view controller: `[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];`). You also have to give the layer a valid size and position (`frame`).
- Animate the layer's `strokeEnd` property from 0 to 1.

Comment: I've added an extra question, how can the coordinates of the points be fixed when the screen sizes vary?

Answer (score 1):

The answer posted by originaluser2 solves everything. You can also try this way, if you want to resize the bezier path for different dievice screens:

You can simply subclass the UIView and customise its drawRect method:

```
  - (void)drawRect: (CGRect)frame
{

    //// Bezier Drawing
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.23370 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.65441 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.49457 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.33088 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.23370 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.65441 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.35870 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.33088 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[bezierPath addCurveToPoint: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.77717 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.65441 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint1: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.63043 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.33088 * CGRectGetHeight(frame)) controlPoint2: CGPointMake(CGRectGetMinX(frame) + 0.77717 * CGRectGetWidth(frame), CGRectGetMinY(frame) + 0.65441 * CGRectGetHeight(frame))];
[UIColor.blackColor setStroke];
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1;
[bezierPath stroke];

}
```

frame 50x50:

[image]

frame 100x100:

[image]

frame 100x50

[image]

This draws a bezier curve in a frame of size 50x50 if you send frame of size 50x50. Also this code get resized automatically based on the frame size it recieves.

Comment: Only problem is that animating in Core Graphics isn't nearly as flexible and performance efficient as Core Animation. Still nice answer though!